# MongoDB/pymongo: Find maximum within nested dictionaries

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to print the value of the field "Output Section" where the field "Probability" has the maximum value, for every key in the field "Input Section".

I am new to MongoDB & pymongo - as far as I can tell, I need to use aggregations somehow like this (example taken from a tutorial):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$by_user", num_tutorial : {$max : "$likes"}}}])
```

I don't get how to apply this to my example though.

```
content = [
        {
        "Stage": "Klage",
        "Heading": "Anträge",
        "Input-Section":

                {
                    "keyword1_keyword2_keyword3":
                            [
                                {
                                "Output-Section": "reply_option_1",
                                "Probability": 0.32},
                                {
                                "Output-Section": "reply_option_2",
                                "Probability": 0.1},
                                {
                                "Output-Section": "reply_option_3",
                                "Probability": 0.58}
                            ],

                    "keyword4_keyword5_keyword6":

                            [
                                {
                                "Output-Section": "reply_option_1",
                                "Probability": 0.35},
                                {
                                "Output-Section": "reply_option_2",
                                "Probability": 0.65}
                            ]

                }

        }
]
```

As a result, I would like to see sth. like 
["reply_option_3", "reply_option_2"]

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: what do you expect for result?

Comment: I updated my question. As a result, I would like to see sth. like ["reply_option_3", "reply_option_2"] or simply a print in any form of the output section with the highest probability associated with it.

Comment: ok. Do you know field keys of your Input-Section sub-document? (keyword1_keyword2_keyword3, etc...)

Comment: Yes. I chose "keyword1_keyword2_keyword3" as a placeholder, but I will replace it with the actual keywords in the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation framework to achieve this :

```
db['02'].aggregate(
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $facet: {
        // facet pipeline 1
                  kw123:[
                    {$project: {input:"$Input-Section.keyword1_keyword2_keyword3"}},
                    {$unwind: {path : "$input"}},
                    {$sort: {"input.Probability": -1}},
                    {$limit: 1},
                    {$project: {"Output-Section":"$input.Output-Section",_id:0 }},
                    ],
                    // facet pipeline 2
                    kw456:[
                    {$project: {input:"$Input-Section.keyword4_keyword5_keyword6"}},
                    {$unwind: {path : "$input"}},
                    {$sort: {"input.Probability": -1}},
                    {$limit: 1},
                    {$project: {"Output-Section":"$input.Output-Section",_id:0 }},],
                }
        },
        // Stage 2
        {
            $project: {
                results:{$setUnion:["$kw123.Output-Section","$kw456.Output-Section"]}
            }
        },
    ],
);
```

It will result :

```
{ 
    "results" : [
        "reply_option_2", 
        "reply_option_3"
    ]
}
```

If you have other fields like keyword1_keyword2_keyword3, just copy and update facet pipeline, and add new field to results.

Hope it helps.